# Copy Contents in Dynamic Generating Textboxes from Add Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have Add button and 6 columns. When I click on add button it generates row dynamically, and delete likewise. problem is I want to use 2 columns to copy the content of one textbox into another. I can do simply for fixed columns but how can I do this for dynamic textbox.

If i write 2 in Amount column and keyup tab, then 2 should come in Total Column. It should happen in every dynamic row.

Kindly tell.

Comment: care to share what you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

I have done it using `jQuery`. Please have a look at it. Please check `keyup` event handler which works with dynamically added rows also. Hope it will help you.

```js
function addRow(){
  //for adding rows dynamically
  var tableElement = document.getElementById("mytable");
  var currentTrLength = tableElement.getElementsByTagName("tr").length;
  var currentTrIndex = currentTrLength-1; //id are ending with _0, _1 and so on
  
  var rowRef = tableElement.getElementsByTagName("tr")[1].cloneNode(true);
  var amountTextElement = rowRef.getElementsByClassName("Amount")[0];
  var totalTextElement = rowRef.getElementsByClassName("Total")[0];
  amountTextElement.id = "Amount_"+currentTrIndex;
  totalTextElement.id = "Amount_"+currentTrIndex;
  
  amountTextElement.value = "";
  totalTextElement.value = "";
  
  document.getElementById("mytable").appendChild(rowRef)
}

function copy(obj){
   var current = obj;
   var currentTr = current.parentElement.parentElement;
   var currentTotalElem = currentTr.getElementsByClassName("Total")[0];
   currentTotalElem.value = current.value;
}

function calculatesum(){

}
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button class="addRow" onclick="addRow()">Add Row</button>
<br/><br/>
 <table id="mytable" style="width:90%">
  <tr>
    <th>Column1</th>
    <th>Column2</th>
    <th>Column3</th>
    <th>Column4</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td><input name='Amount[]' class='form-control Amount' style='width:180px' type='text' onblur='calculatesum();' onkeyup='copy(this);' id='Amount_0' size='10' /></td>
    <td><input name='Total[]' style='width:180px' class='form-control Total' type='text' id='Total_0' size='10' /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So do you mean that you can't use jQuery at all? and you want simple plain JavaScript based solution?

Comment: @RakHad - updated the snippet code. Removed the jQuery dependancy. Now its a plain javascript code. And please don't call me a sir...because I am not... `:)`!

Comment: r u still there vijayp? want to discuss something with u. :)

Comment: so you mean to say...initially you have only table header with column names. You don't have any row with text box in it. And on button click you are adding first row to your table. Is that correct?

Comment: yes..please go ahead and update your question to add 1) Your initial `<table>` and `button` structure 2) Your JS add function.

Comment: @RakHad - i can see `$` in your javascript code. So its uses jQuery..right?

Comment: added newer answer @RakHad

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at below code:

in your `<td>` code you have call to `copy()` on `onblur` event as `onkeyup='calculatesum();' onblur='copy(this);'` I have passed current element's reference by `this`

```js
 var cc = 1; 
function addTableRow(jQtable){ 
  var id=cc; 
  jQtable.each(function() { 
    var data = "<tr><td class='Arial_4C8966'><input name='Amount[]' class='form-control Amount[]' style='width:180px' type='text' onkeyup='calculatesum();' onblur='copy(this);' id='Amount_" + cc + "' size='10' /></td><td class='Arial_4C8966'><input name='Total[]' style='width:180px' class='form-control Total' type='text' id='Total_" + cc + "' size='10' /></td></tr>";
    
    var $table = $(this); 
    var n = $('tr:last td', this).length; 
    var tds = data;
    cc++; 
    if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) 
    { 
      $('tbody', this).append(tds); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
      $(this).append(tds); 
    } 
  }); 
}

function copy(obj){
   var current = obj;
   var currentTr = current.parentElement.parentElement;
   var currentTotalElem = currentTr.getElementsByClassName("Total")[0];
   currentTotalElem.value = current.value;
}

function calculatesum(){

}
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row clearfix"> <div class="col-md-12 column"> 
   <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="dynamicInput">
     <tr class="Form_Text_Label"> 
       <td align="center" >AMOUNT*</td> 
       <td align="center" >TOTAL*</td> 
     </tr> 
   </table>
   </div> 
    <fieldset style="width:95%;"> 
      <div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <input type="button" value="Add" class="frmBtns" onClick="addTableRow($('#dynamicInput'));" style="font-family:Calibri; font-size:15px; " > <br> 
          </div>
        </div>
   </fieldset>
```

Comment: vijayp there is a problem!
OK?
i wanna share the reasons vijayp

Comment: sorry..but i really don't know cleanzone template jquery libraries...:(

Comment: hey..sorry...ya tell me...show me 6 columns html.. I believe you will show me `var data = "<tr><td ` having 6 `<td>`

Comment: @RakHad - i have few question for you. 1) HTML i can see ` <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="dynamicInput"> <fieldset style="width:95%;"> <div>` . You can not have `<fieldset>` and `<div>` directly inside `<table>`. 2) I can see `</div> </span> <div>` inside HTML. Where is its opening tag>

Comment: Kindly put your code into jsfiddle...copy pasting from comments is somewhat tedious. I have left for the day.will see your code tomorrow. But please ping me back Fiddle url. Thanks

Comment: Still haven't got the Fiddle link.

Comment: i tried it by copying code from each comment. But its failing. Don't know why. Can you post newer question with entire code and ping me question link OR ping me broken fiddle link. I just want entire code in single piece. Do it ASAP.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33164340/dynamic-copy-contents-from-textboxes

@Vijayp, this is the link to my new question with full fledge 6 columns . Fix it ASAP the way you fixed 2 columns. same copy content of Column AMount_ into Column Total_ :)

Comment: added answer to your question.

Comment: see the `function copy_data(obj)`. this is the simple function.

Comment: Hi @RakHad. Yes I am online

Comment: Your reputation & expertees is very cool. Life is all about learning. 
P.S there is last query to my code, i mean last addition. Should i ask you? :)
Gd morning & you promised ur email to be shared with me.....

Comment: Good morning...ya sure...drop me your query at following email address user1858`@`hotmail.com, will take a look at it once i am somewhat free...

Comment: Very unique email id u have, :P. I am sharing with u here, its not long so no need to share here.

Comment: <label class="col-sm-3 text-right ">Grand Total :</label>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
                <td class="Arial_4C8966"><input name="total_quantity" type="text" class="form-control" id="total_quantity"  size="10"  /></td>

this is my new textbox code which lies outside dynamic table rows. I want to sum the numeric values in column Amount_ and put the sum in above textbox... 

i have right a code and its not working fully. should i also share my piece of code? @vijayP

Comment: just 1 question. Why name and id of this field is `total_quantity`. I think it should be `grand_total`. I will add above piece of HTML with this modification in running code snippet and will update the code. Is that fine?

Comment: yeah sure...add it and update this. i just gave my own customize id name, u can use grand_total also. :)
@vijayP

P.S : Write Javascript function sum (),. something like that, that sum values and place in Textbox.

Comment: Pingme on Update after adding sum function. @vijayP.

Comment: updated the ans to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33164340/dynamic-copy-contents-from-textboxes. Added the `function CalculateGrandTotal()` there