# Dynamic Copy Contents from Textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my full code. Dynamic rows are generating on add button and deleting on delete icon image. i want to copy the contents of 2 columns from it.
This is my full code. Dynamic rows are generating on add button and deleting on delete icon image. i want to copy the contents of 2 columns from it.

**JavaScript Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var cc = 1;

    function addTableRow(jQtable){
        var id=cc;
        jQtable.each(function() {
            var data = "<tr><td class='Arial_4C8966' align='center'><input name='InvoiceDate[]' type='date' class='form-control'  placeholder='' style='width:160px'  id='InvoiceDate_" + cc + "' size='10'  onclick='showData(this.value," + cc + ")'/></td><td class='Arial_4C8966'><input name='Details[]' type='text'  class='form-control' style='width:240px'  id='Details_" + cc + "' size='10'/></td><td class='Arial_4C8966'><input name='ReceiptNo[]' type='text'  class='form-control' style='width:180px' id='ReceiptNo_" + cc + "' size='10' /></td><td class='Arial_4C8966'><input name='Amount[]' class='form-control'  style='width:180px' type='text'   onblur='copy_data(this);' id='Amount_" + cc + "' size='10'   /></td><td class='Arial_4C8966'><input name='Total[]' style='width:180px'  class='form-control'  type='text' id='Total_" + cc + "' size='10' /></td><td class='Arial_4C8966'><img src='assets/img/pictures.png' style='cursor:pointer; border:0px; width:16px;' onclick='setDeletedID("+ cc +");$(this).parent().parent().remove();' />
            var $table = $(this);
            var n = $('tr:last td', this).length;
            var tds = data; 
            cc++;
            if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
                $('tbody', this).append(tds);
            } else {
                $(this).append(tds);
            }
        });
    }

    function setDeletedID(itemID){
        objReceiptNo=document.getElementById('ReceiptNo_'+itemID)
        if(objReceiptNo.value!=''){
            if(document.getElementById('txtDeletedIDs').value==''){
               document.getElementById('txtDeletedIDs').value= objReceiptNo.value;
            }else{
               document.getElementById('txtDeletedIDs').value+= ', '+objReceiptNo.value;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**HTML CODE:**

```
 <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12 column">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="dynamicInput">
            <tr class="Form_Text_Label">
                <td align="center">INVOICE DATE*</td>
                <td align="center">DETAILS*</td>
                <td align="center">RECEIPT NO*</td>
                <td align="center">AMOUNT*</td>

                <td align="center">TOTAL*</td>
                <td align="center"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="button" value="Add" class="frmBtns" onclick="addTableRow($('#dynamicInput'));"
        onblur="copy_data(this);" style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 15px;">


    <br>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "i want to copy the contents of 2 columns from it.". please be specific in your question

Comment: means i want to copy the content of Amount_ textbox into Total_textbox in this dynamic generated, 
P.S: Amount_ and Total_ are 2 columns. @user3477283.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at revised HTML and JS code. Hope it will work for you:

```js
var cc = 1;

CalculateGrandTotal();


 function addTableRow(jQtable){
  var id=cc;
  jQtable.each(function() {
   var data = "<tr><td class='Arial_4C8966' align='center'><input name='InvoiceDate[]' type='date' class='form-control'  placeholder='' style='width:160px'  id='InvoiceDate_" + cc + "' size='10'  onclick='showData(this.value," + cc + ")'/></td><td class='Arial_4C8966'><input name='Details[]' type='text'  class='form-control' style='width:240px'  id='Details_" + cc + "' size='10'/></td><td class='Arial_4C8966'><input name='ReceiptNo[]' type='text'  class='form-control' style='width:180px' id='ReceiptNo_" + cc + "' size='10' /></td><td class='Arial_4C8966'><input name='Amount[]' class='form-control'  style='width:180px' type='text'   onblur='copy_data(this);' id='Amount_" + cc + "' size='10'   /></td><td class='Arial_4C8966'><input name='Total[]' style='width:180px'  class='form-control Total'  type='text' id='Total_" + cc + "' size='10' /></td><td class='Arial_4C8966'><img src='assets/img/pictures.png' style='cursor:pointer; border:0px; width:16px;' onclick='setDeletedID("+ cc +");$(this).parent().parent().remove();' />";
   var $table = $(this);
   var n = $('tr:last td', this).length;
   var tds = data; 
   cc++;
   if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
    $('tbody', this).append(tds);
   } else {
    $(this).append(tds);
   }
  });
 }
    function copy_data(obj){
    var current = $(obj);
    var currentTr = current.closest("tr");
    var currentTotalElem = currentTr.find(".Total");
    currentTotalElem.val(current.val());
      
       CalculateGrandTotal();
 }
 
//calculate the grand total
    function CalculateGrandTotal(){
      var grandTotal = 0;
      $(".Total").each(function(){
        var currVal = $(this).val();
        if(!isNaN(currVal))
        {
          grandTotal += parseFloat(currVal);
        }
      });
      
      $("#grand_total").val(grandTotal);
    }

 function setDeletedID(itemID){
  objReceiptNo=document.getElementById('ReceiptNo_'+itemID)
  if(objReceiptNo.value!=''){
   if(document.getElementById('txtDeletedIDs').value==''){
      document.getElementById('txtDeletedIDs').value= objReceiptNo.value;
   }else{
      document.getElementById('txtDeletedIDs').value+= ', '+objReceiptNo.value;
   }
  }
 }
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 

<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12 column">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="dynamicInput">
            <tr class="Form_Text_Label">
                <td align="center">INVOICE DATE*</td>
                <td align="center">DETAILS*</td>
                <td align="center">RECEIPT NO*</td>
                <td align="center">AMOUNT*</td>

                <td align="center">TOTAL*</td>
                <td align="center"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="button" value="Add" class="frmBtns" onclick="addTableRow($('#dynamicInput'));"
        style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 15px;"></input>


    <br>

<label class="col-sm-3 text-right ">Grand Total :</label> <div class="col-sm-3"> <td class="Arial_4C8966"><input name="grand_total" type="text" class="form-control" id="grand_total" size="10" />

</div>
```

Please try to use above JS and HTML code as it is. Replace your corresponding code with above one. Please note: your `function setDeletedID` doesn't work as provided HTML don't contain any element with an `id` `txtDeletedIDs`. Please check that again. Thanks.

Comment: OK...but this will be my last work for this question. Give me some time.

Comment: Now don't be rude vijayp. Appreciate ur time & effort. tThanku so much.Its working now. :(

Comment: have you ran the code snippet. Its working..right? If it is running well then i will request you to blindly copy 1) `function addTableRow(jQtable)` 2) `function copy_data(obj)` 3) entire HTML code without `1.9.0/jquery.min.js` `<script>` tag. It will solve your problem. Don't try to make your code working by looking at my answer. Go other way round.

Comment: Got any success @RakHad?

Comment: Now don't be rude @RakHad.... `:)`. Tell me what happened? Does that helped you..?

Comment: I shared with you a msg on previous one @Vijayp. Waiting for your reply back. :)
Do u have any email? would ne nice to be in contact with you.

Comment: Hello @RakHad. Hey sorry. Didn't saw your previous ping earlier as I avoid coming online on weekends... :) I will share my email soon with you. Will ping you on Monday.

Comment: Just seen u online...There is a problem on other question. u availaible? need assistance? @vijayP.

Comment: @RakHad ping me the SO question link.

Comment: u gave me email. i mailed u and never get reply. seen u online and msged u. don't u use email?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34311091/migrate-from-asp-classics-to-asp-netinline-coding-using-vb-executereader
@vijayP

Comment: Waiting @vijayP
Link is in above comment.

Comment: I thought u will assist me but u didn't replied. Now don't be rude @vijayP